# Search / Sort Plugin for Posts and Pages?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

My boss has asked me to help him find a search and sort plugin for our clients' WP site we're building. They need something similar to this: http://www.restaurant.com/

The site will have listings of businesses and the client would like the users to be able to get search results (as a list of pages on the site) based on zip code (I think a distance radius would be nice), keywords, etc. The pages would need to be tagged somehow I'm assuming?

I've seen a couple plugins for sorting blog posts in wordpress but we need something for pages as well. Any suggestions would be a great help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install plugin: Custom Post Type UI
and create a taxonomy for postal codes and other values ​​that you need.
The new taxonomies can also associate them to pages and post.

To filter based on these taxonomies I would probably create a simple ajax script , like this:

```
$title = $_POST[ 'title' ]; /*for example: zip code*/
$filter = $_POST[ 'filter' ]; /*for example: 09090 (Italian zip code)*/
$order = $_POST[ 'order' ]; /* ASC or DSC*/
$args = array (
        'term' => $term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
             'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => $filter,
                  'field'    => 'id',
                  'terms'    => $title,
                  'order by' => 'taxonomy_name',
                  'order'    => $order

                  )
              )
         );
```